# Strange behaviour of "ps aux" in the CPU time column

Tags: ps, process-management, cpu-usage

I am periodically running "ps aux" that outputs values in a following format:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

If I understand **TIME** is a cumulative CPU time, cumulative in a sense that it does represent total CPU time spend on this process. Here I would assume that this value can only raise as time can not be unconsumed. However I am finding myself in a situation where the value actually *drops* (while PID did not change so that means that process was not restarted). My question therefore is why such behaviour?

The sample how generated data (with problem in before the last column) looks like is here:

```
2017-08-04T07-05-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:33 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-10-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:34 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-15-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:35 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-20-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:37 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-25-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:38 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-30-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:39 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-35-01 user  16493  0.3  0.4  59536 28416 ?        Sl   Aug01  15:40 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-40-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:21 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-45-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:21 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-50-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:21 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T07-55-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:22 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T08-00-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:22 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T08-05-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:22 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T08-11-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:22 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T08-15-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:22 /usr/local/myprocess
2017-08-04T08-20-01 user  16493  0.0  0.4  60560 29608 ?        Sl   Aug01   1:22 /usr/local/myprocess
```

Full script that runs as cronjob and generates my data is this one (just actual process names are different):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

proc_names="MyProcessToWatch1 MyProcessToWatch2 MyProcessToWatch3"
current_date=$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")
hostname=$(hostname)

for proc_name in ${proc_names}
do
    procs_to_watch=$(ps -ef | grep "${proc_name}" | grep -v grep | grep -v vi | grep -v tail | grep -v less | grep -v "ps -" | awk '{print $2}')
    for proc_id in ${procs_to_watch}
    do
        proc_start_ts=$(ls -ld --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S" /proc/${proc_id} | awk '{ print $(NF-1) }')
        log_file="/tmp/performance_data/performance_${proc_name}_${proc_start_ts}_${hostname}_${proc_id}.log"
        echo -n "${current_date} " >> ${log_file} 2>&1
        ps aux | grep "${proc_name}" | grep ${proc_id} >> ${log_file} 2>&1
    done
done
```

Comment: I don't suppose `LC_TIME` is set anywhere along the way?

Comment: No it is not ... How could that have an impact?

Comment: It affects the TIME output; just ruling things out.

Comment: If you can reproduce this, could you log the contents of `/proc/16493/stat` (replacing the PID by the correct one)? This is where `ps` gets its data, and there's more data in the `stat` file, it could provide a clue.